# Can't install GNU GSL library from source

Tags: compiling, debugging, gnu

I'm trying to install the GNU GSL Scientific library 1.16 from source under Ubuntu Server 14. I've already done that several times under OS X with no problems, but I keep getting the same error on the Ubuntu machine. I've already taken the steps proposed by the GNU GSL Installation instruction in case something goes wrong, i.e.

> If there are problems building the library try using
>
> ```
>     ./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking
> ```

So the installation is supposed to be like:

```
./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking
sudo make
sudo make install
```

But the compilation step fails with the following error:

> file.c:102:0: fatal error: error writing to /tmp/ccF9p6T9.s: No space left on device
>
> #undef  BASE_CHAR
>
> ^
>   compilation terminated.

Any ideas? I used the same source to compile the library under OS X with no errors at all. I don't get where the "No space left on device" error comes from, since I have a ton of free space.

**EDIT**

Adding the output of `df -h /tmp`

```
File.system   Size Used  Available Used% Mounted at
overflow         1,0M         468K  556K           46% /tmp
```

P.S.

I'm aware of the GSL package in `apt-get`repositories, but I really need to install it from source.

Comment: Is your `/tmp/` partition separate? Run `df -h /tmp` and post the output.

Comment: You most likely need more ram/swap/a bigger swap partition

Comment: @Grammargeek the machine has 128GB of RAM)

Comment: @codingman I've posted the output

Comment: Your `/tmp` directory is full.  Have you not restarted the box in a long time?

Comment: @ThomasW. Yeah, we never turn it off. It's always computing some stuff.

Comment: @Grammargeek Swap/RAM doesn't have much to do with `/tmp`

Comment: Except if `/tmp` is mounted as a ramdisk, which doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: "tmpfs is a temporary filesystem that resides in memory and/or your swap partition(s), depending on how much you fill it up. Mounting directories as tmpfs can be an effective way of speeding up accesses to their files, or to ensure that their contents are automatically cleared upon reboot."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message gives you the exact cause of the issue, and I've wrapped it in three asterisks below:

```
file.c:102:0: fatal error: ***error writing to /tmp/ccF9p6T9.s: No space left on device***
```

This means that your `/tmp` directory, whIch holds temporary files and such, is full.  You've said that you never reboot the box, because it's always computing some stuff.  My guess is its using `/tmp` to store computational data in a temporary location.  That directory usually is cleared out on reboot and in other cases.

The problem is, when `/tmp` gets full you can run into a lot of problems.  From your `df -h` output above, your `/tmp` was mounted as 'overflow'.  Likely what happened is your root filesystem got filled up, and `/tmp` wasn't defined as its own partition, and the system remounted `/tmp` as an 'overflow' disk, which is limited in size.

So, you've got two things you need to do:

1. Figure out whether your `/` partition is out of space.  `df -h` on its own will give you a rundown of everything.
2. Remove old data from your disk (either delete it or move it elsewhere off the system), and the `/tmp` directory.  Something's eating your space and that's a bad thing.
3. Consider a reboot from time to time, during a regular maintenance period or something.  This way, your `/tmp` directory will get cleared out every so often, and you can apply kernel updates and such.

Comment: I've never faced this issue before and googling the error message haven't helped.  After all I simply replaced `/tmp` with a bigger partition. Thank you.